# Send list of opened tabs from chrome extension to electron application

Tags: google-chrome-extension, electron, desktop, browser-extension

I am currently coding an electron desktop application for which I need to get information on the opened tabs in the user's browser. Therefore, I need to create a chrome extension *(correct me if I'm wrong)* that is able to send a list of all currently opened browser URLs/tabs to the electron application.

###### My questions are:

- How do I make the extension send the tab-list to my app?
- How do I make the extension send the required data everytime the tab-list changes *(new tab is opened / tab is closed / URL in tab changes)*

To be honest, I just tried to copy code from the internet, as I am not very familiar with the coding of chrome extensions. However, nothing really helped me and now I am hoping to find some advice on here.

Comment: See chrome.tabs.query and chrome.tabs.onUpdated for the extension. In your app you can listen on a localhost port/socket and in the extension you would use `fetch` or `WebSocket` to connect.

Comment: Alright, I will try it with this method, thanks!